# AIX NFS mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, aix

This is my /etc/exports in AIX NFS server(10.2.150.211).

```
/app_src/g2s/workspace -vers=3,access=[10.2.10.204],rw=[10.2.10.204],root=[10.2.10.204]
```

Of course, I run exportfs -av after renewing

I tried this command on a Ubuntu NFS client(10.2.10.204).

```
sudo mount -t nfs -o vers=3 10.2.150.211:/app_src/g2s/workspace ./import
```

However it returns

```
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 10.2.150.211:/app_src/g2s/workspace
```

How can I solve it ?

Comment: Does your Ubuntu server have a different interface that it's using to get to the AIX NFS server?

Comment: it seems permission problem , check the owner and group of share and permission on that , also check by disabling firewall and SE-Linux on the server

Comment: @Ijaz Khan What permission should I check ?, I think the permission is allowed by `/etc/exports` file.

Comment: @asleea:  Check the server's error log!

Comment: @Julie Pelletier Where can I check the log in AIX?

Comment: You probably need to enable the use of reserved ports or disable the portcheck on the AIX server. Please post the output of `nfso -aF|grep port`

Comment: @IjazAhmadKhan AIX doesn't use SELinux.

Comment: @asleea  /etc/syslog.conf is the configuration for syslog. This is AIX: have you tried using smitty to configure etc/hosts and nfs ?

Answer (score 1):

You need reverse lookup in DNS to allow NFS to mount.  I have the same issue:

```
[root@usmd1lnx095 init.d]# host 10.1.11.173
Host 173.11.1.10.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
[root@usmd1lnx095 init.d]#
```

I'm trying to get my DNS fixed.  I have an AIX server that mounts a filesystem to MANY servers.  I just built this one and it can't mount.  It's DNS, fer sher.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you don't include IP addresses inside `[..]` and just list them as normal:

```
/app_src/g2s/workspace -vers=3,access=10.2.10.204,rw=10.2.10.204,root=10.2.10.204
```

You should be able to verify the export is correct with

```
showmount -e
```

Comment: `showmount -e` returns `export list for psrsmsapp01: /app_src/g2s/workspace 10.2.10.204` but it still deny access.

Answer (score -1):

We had the same problems, I fixed this problem after add ip and hostname in /etc/hosts from NFS AIX Server.